# Represent Wikipedia in Graph form

Tags: python, computer-science, wikipedia

I want to represent whole Wikipedia in a graph form, like each article is a node and if one article contains link of other article then they share an edge.
Since this will be too many hits so I will need to make requests locally ( setup Wikipedia locally ).
Can you guide me how to achieve this ( tell me about libraries or tools that will be helpful ) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a dump from Wikipedia [here.](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/)
From your 'python' tag i assume you want to use python to crawl the data and generate the graph.
I can recommend the following modules:

- requests - for retrieving the websites
- Beautifulsoup - for parsing html
- scrapy - alternative for beautifulsoup
- pymongodb - Together with a mongodb of course. Mongodb is a good choice because it's document oriented
- matplotlib - For visualization
- graphviz - also a good choice for visualization
- networkx - visualization and manipulation of graphs

Comment: If my answer helped you solve the problem I would appreciate it if you could mark it as solution :)

Comment: networkx is not just for plotting graphs, it allows lots of requests/manipulations on them